# Antique Schlage Door Knob - Can't reassemble

Tags: doors, lock

From an old Schlage outside/inside door knob (I think it dates back to the 1950's).  I can't find where the retaining clip goes.  The front of the door is a handle with an old-fashioned lever[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the solution, so far.  (I will know for sure, once it's on the door).  The little (moveable) tab that holds the finishing plate on bottom is holding the retaining clip, with gravity keeping it down.  Both finishing plate and door knob seem secure.  Somehow, I pictured this in a tighter area when I took it off a month ago.

Another lesson I learned.  Take photos when disassembling.  I had originally planned to replace the door knob so saw no need to.  It would've been too difficult of a project to replace. And I didn't want to end up getting an entire new door if I couldn't find an exact match or didn't measure a for new one's location properly.

Also, I was "almost 100% sure" the clip went on the front of that silver back plate with the finishing plate in front of it.  It looks like I was 100% wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Congrats on figuring this out! Please give yourself a check mark on this answer so others will know that this has a successful resolution and they can rely on it if they have a similar issue.

Comment: I've found the "take lots of photos during teardown" approach useful on several occasions now.

Answer (score 1):

I think it holds the finish plate on. Look at the base plate you see the  bump outs clip may go in there. Then push over it a snap down to hold the finish in the lower notch.

Comment: When you put on the trim? Does the bottom notch click in and hold it tight. And the top is loose.

Comment: The bottom notch clicks in, the top is slightly loose.  The door knob itself seems to be falling downward.  My thinking is that the clip is used somewhere between the finish plate and silver plate to stabilize the door knob.  I can't find anyplace that it would sensibly fit.

Comment: The very top two bump outs maybe .And look at inside  of the copper rim for marks . See a little green were clip may have rest.

Comment: I don't think Schlage would design a decorative face plate to hold the lock in place. You're either missing pieces or that clip holds the knob in. The face plate is probably just loose from being bent out of shape. Try putting it on the shaft and up against the structure plate, if that's not where it goes to straighten out the lock, something else is broken.

Comment: Do you have more parts? And when you install them .What happens? Does the finish stay,or loose?Knob pulls off?

Comment: Schlage  Makes the inside face plates to come off ,to get at the screws to remove lock set. Yes they do not hold the lock in,  The catch goes in first,then the lever side slides in, The part with the lock release goes inside, then the trim goes on to hide the screws.

Comment: Put together (minus the retaining clip) the knob is functional, but very loose.  The faceplate does stay on (slightly loose which it wasn't before).  This is an old house (and door which I just painted).  The key itself was long ago lost so it only opens and closes from the inside.  The outside lever has always been inoperable (It simply doesn't go down, even unlocked).  All pieces are present.  Thanks all, for your assistance (Spent a frustrating day with this, and will try the possible solutions tomorrow).

Answer (score 0):

Your face plate is damaged.(you may already know this) If you still have this nob. Did you remove the key pin? If you didnt. you can try and then try to unlock the thumb trigger. The key pin may be inserted wrong. It does look like in picture 3 the key is not all the way in. you need a door key to put it in right (I think). forgot you wrote it was lost.

Comment: Are you sure you've answered the correct question? The OP didn't say anything about the knob not unlocking, only that he didn't know where the retaining clip was to go.

Answer (score 0):

That's my lock! It's an e series that is expensive.

https://absupply.net/pdf/E-and-EB-Ser-Lock-1982-Cat-Pag.pdf

[image]

Comment: That would be mine also.  Figured it out and repainted the door.  It was probably the first time in twenty years that anyone could get into the front door from outside.  My development was built between the 1920's and 50's...To this day when I see others front doors, I don't see another one of these types of locks.  My belief is most people replaced the door in all that time.  I'm too cheap as it's an odd size.